# Request processing time in python

Tags: python, selenium, server, automated-tests, load-testing

I'm trying to test a web application using selenium python. I've wrote a script to mimic a user. It logs in to the server, generates some reports and so on. It is working fine.
Now, I need to see how much time the server is taking to process a specific request. 
Is there a way to find that from the same python code?
Any alternate method is acceptable.

Note:

- The server is in the same LAN
- Also I don't have privileges to do anything at the server side. So anything I can do is from outside the server.

Any sort of help is appreciable. Thank you

Comment: you can use curl, the python wrapper is called `pycurl`

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know what requests are sent to the server. All pages are in jsp. My script just finds the element and click. Is there a way to see what requests are sent when an element is clicked? Only then I can use curl, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the w3c HTTP access log field, "time-taken."  This will report on every single request the time in milliseconds maximally.  On some platforms the precision reported is more granular.  In order for a web server, an application server with an HTTP access layer, an enterprise services bus with an HTTP access layer (for SOAP and REST calls) to be fully w3c standards compliant this log value must be available for inclusion in the HTTP access logs.

You will see every single granular request and the time required for processing from first byte of receipt at the server to the last byte sent minus the final TCP ACK at the end.